# How do you pass in HTTP headers to make a request from an API?

Tags: angularjs, api, http

Using Angular, I'm trying to pass in HTTP headers with the request, “App-Id” and “App-Key” to get data from [this API](http://apidocs.bookingbug.com/public.html#!/company/get_company_company_id).

I tried setting the headers like this:

```
 $http.defaults.headers.common["App-Id"] = '5a3d8b8d';
 $http.defaults.headers.common["App-Key"] = '738e9aca62e7465446b7be8fe4219ffa';
```

but I got a `Response for preflight is invalid` error.

http://jsfiddle.net/9Ymvt/4573/

Comment: Squirrl: how did you manage to get your App-Id and App-Key ? I can't figure it out in my account...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

### Adding Headers to an `$http` Request on a Per Request Basis

To add headers to a `$http` request on a per request basis, add them to the `headers` property of the `$http` config object.

```
var xheaders = {};
xheaders["App-Id"] = '5a3d8b8d';
xheaders["App-Key"] = '738e9aca62e7465446b7be8fe4219ffa';

var xurl = 'https://uk.bookingbug.com/api/v1';
var configObj = { method: 'GET',
                  url: xurl, 
                  headers: xheaders
                };
$http(configObj)
    .then(function onFulfilled(response) {
        console.log(response);
        vm.headers = response.config.headers;
        vm.data = response.data
    }).catch( function onRejection(errorResponse) {
        console.log("Error: ", errorResponse.status);
        console.log(errorResponse);
        vm.error = errorResponse;
    })
;
```

The code was getting pre-flight errors because it was using the incorrect URL. The correct base URL is `https://uk.bookingbug.com/api/v1` which supports `App-Id` headers and CORS.

The [DEMO on JSFiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/ew1jda9t/).

Comment: Yes I got that eventually myself.  How could you tell that was the correct URL?  For me it was mostly trial and error.

Answer (score 1):

I do not think this is a complete answer to your question, but here is what I have in my project:

```
var app = angular.module('app', ['ngRoute']);
app.config(function($routeProvider) {
  // code for routes
});
app.config(['$httpProvider', function($httpProvider) {
  $httpProvider.defaults.useXDomain = true;
  delete $httpProvider.defaults.headers.common['X-Requested-With'];
}]);
```

This solves my problem with CORS. If you want to do another type of header, you probably can [find your answer here](https://docs.angularjs.org/api/ng/provider/$httpProvider).

Answer (score 1):

Preflight errors are related to CORS. You might want to look at rack-cors to enable cross-site api calls via javascript. There is a manual configuration here: https://gist.github.com/dhoelzgen/cd7126b8652229d32eb4